# How to use kendo-ui asp.net mvc in visual studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to use kendo-ui asp.net mvc in visual studio 2015. I install telerik package and the kendo-ui added to my visual studio.

I create a new kendo-ui asp.net mvc project. When i open index.cshtml file and write

```
@{Html.Kendo().DatePicker().Name...}
```

the inheritence dose not show Kendo() method and i cant use it.
How can i create Controls such as a DatePicker in kendo-ui 2016 and visual studio 2015?

Comment: Do you have/have purchased the MVC Helper from Kendo?

Comment: no i install it for free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to check when you don't see something in the intellisense, is your project "References". It is the only place the compiler looks to find the used libraries. In your case you need a reference to `Kendo.Mvc.dll` as described [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5#add-kendomvcdll-reference).

Next, it's worth noting that `Html.Kendo()` is an "[Extension Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)" and is simply a shorthand for `Kendo.Mvc.UI.HtmlHelperExtension.Kendo(Html)`. So, when you have the required reference, the latter form should work; But to be able to use the shorter form, you need to import the `Kendo.Mvc.UI` namespace in your cshtml file. There are two ways to do this:

- Add `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` to the top of the cshtml file, or
- Add this line: `<add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>` to the `namespaces` section in `Views\web.config` in your project. This imports the namespace for every cshtml file under the `Views` folder, but you might need to reload the project for this to work.

Anyway, please follow [this guide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-5) to be sure you won't forget anything.

Comment: thanks . i add @using Kendo.Mvc.UI to the top of the cshtml file and its work correctly

Answer (score 1):

Check your Views\Web.config. It should have like:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            ...
            <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc"/>
            <add namespace="Kendo.Mvc.UI"/>
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

or add `@using Kendo.Mvc.UI` to index.cshtml

Comment: No , where can i add this? can you give me a simple code to add a datepicker?

Comment: I add it but this error show : the type or namespace 'kendo' could not be found

Comment: @saedbfd see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29521927/4275342) answer